# Scientific-Sounding Adjective or Noun to Describe a Creature with Multiple Heads

Tags: single-word-requests

There are certain mythological creatures that have more than one head. I want to find a word that can be used to categorize them in a way that sounds scientific. I hope to create much of the same feeling of the word "quadrupedal" meaning "four legged". Here is one example:

Dogs and cats are quadrupedal animals. Cerebus and Chimera are ________ animals.

I initially considered "multi-headed" but have since rejected it as it sounds a bit contrived in my particular application.

**Further Clarification**

- must sound scientific
- adjective preferred, noun is acceptable
- Latin root preferred (in the hopes it sounds more scientific)
- If no such words exists, I will accept a fictional word so long as it
  sounds scientific and convincing

Comment: try a google search - there are many

Comment: FWIW, both Latin and Greek have provided source material for scientific terminology; don't rule out either language, or even combinations of them.

Comment: I hate to be a killjoy but when [a google search for science multiple head leads directly to a Wikipedia article for the desired word](http://archive.is/kD2xa), the question is probably [too simple](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/22/are-some-questions-too-simple/), which is probably why we got four answers stating the same thing all at once. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Why, hello there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the adjective *[polycephalous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polycephalous)*, succinctly defined by the Online Oxford Dictionary as:

> Having many heads.

It has a Greek, not Latin root as it comes from the Greek words *poly* (πολύ, many) and *kephalē* (κεφαλή, head), but should sound both scientific and convincing seeing as it is a real scientific term. For example, there is a pretty cactus named *[Echinocactus polycephalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinocactus_polycephalus)*.

Comment: And here I always thought that *all* cacti were echinulate. :)

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, make it up in Greek and see if it already exists:

[Polycephalic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polycephalic), polycephalous  adj.

[Polycephaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycephaly) n.

Answer (score 2):

*Polycephalic* is precisely the word you want. Greek not Latin,(*poly*- : many, as in polygon, for example. *cephalos* : head ) but surely technical-sounding all the same.